# In a fight, all else equal, would someone with higher fast twitch muscles tire out faster than someone with higher slow twitch muscles?

Tags: muscle, endurance

Suppose two people get into a fight.

All else equal, one has higher fast twitch muscle ratio while the other has higher slow twitch muscle ratio.

Can we say that the longer the fight goes on, the person with the higher slow twitch muscles would have the advantage as his opponent will tire out first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it would be impossible for a fight to be of such low intensity and long duration that slow twitch fibres would have an advantage. Slow twitch fibres are only advantageous during prolonged submaximal (aerobic) exercise activities like long distance running and cycling.

So in a 50km bicycle race, comparing two people with different fibre type ratios but all else being equal, the person with mainly type I fibres might be able to ride at 32km/h for the duration of the race, while the person with mainly type II fibres might only be able to sustain 30km/h, because they can't put out as much power with their aerobic energy system. Whereas in a 4km race, the type II fibre cyclist might average 40km/h, while the type I fibre cyclist might only be able to average 33km/h, because they are barely able to utilise their anaerobic energy system.